# Tridion OutboundEmail - Contact synchronization from several Presentation servers?

Tags: email, synchronization, contacts, tridion-2011, outbound

I'm facing a problem with OutboundEmail Synchronization for Contacts.

We have the following scenario : 2 load-balanced CMS servers and 3 load-balanced CDE web servers located in different data centers.
Each CDE web server will have it's own SQL server for broker DB and OutboundEmail Subscription + Tracking DB.

If I install local OutboundEmail Subscription + Tracking DB on each CDE, how can I process the Contacts Synchronization from the 3 CDE servers, knowing that for a specific Tridion publication you can only specify 1 synchronization target containing 1 url to profilesync.aspx ?

And idem for Tracking Synchronization.

I must be missing something ...

Any suggestion please?

Comment: AFAIK I don't think you can do this with the AM & Tracking dbs, they must be the same for all CD servers... I could be wrong, hence not putting this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, it's also my feeling. But the "SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Installation Manual.pdf" mentions this in section 7.7.1: "Note: You can install Subscription and Tracking on one or several presentation servers, and these can use the same or different Tracking and Subscription databases." I suppose this is ok only if you plan to use different synchronization targets in some of your publications.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is currently not supported, we do support multiple presentation servers but as you mentioned you can only specify one synchronization target under a publication

without going into detail there were compelling reasons not to support this scenario at that point in time, but it is on our backlog

I can think of a couple of options to solve it in this version:

- use one database, but i'm guessing the reason to split it up over 3 data-centers is for fail-over/redunancy and/or geographical reasons
- setup synchronization/tracking on one server and replicate data to the other 2 databases, note that the replication needs to be bi-directional